Where do you set default values when registering a user?
i am currently developing a web application in which the user should have the possibility to register. For this I have built a VueJS web application and a Golang REST API.
However, the backend is now to be extended so that certain default values are to be set for the user. These default values relate to a different table, i.e. not the table in which the user is saved but a table in which the user-specific settings are stored. I am now wondering at what point this would be optimal from an architectural point of view or whether a good procedure has already been established for this.
Does it make sense to send 2 requests from the client to the backend? One for registration and one for the user-specific settings? Or should the user controller that was specified to create the user be extended so that it also sets the default values for the settings?

it really depends on you and your requirements.

Use a single request.
If you use two they are not linked as a transaction. You want both to succeed or both to fail. Also there are dependencies - the user-specific settings will almost certainly be foreign keyed to the user record.
Put the inserts to both tables into a single service method that is wrapped in a single transaction.
